# Would a moderator edit out the deprecated [learning] tag from the locked posts which include it?

Tags: support, tag-cleanup

Over the past couple of days I've been editing out the deprecated [learning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag from the several dozen posts which had it, since most of those posts are either off-topic or don't need such a useless tag. Only three posts still have the tag, but I cannot remove the tag from them because they are locked. Would a moderator please edit these last few posts so that the tag will be completely removed from the system?

Comment: Tags are removed, it would be nice if SE would provide a better way to blacklist

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks, but it looks like one post still has the tagged. It might be because [learning] is the only tag on it (I would use [basic] instead). It might also be because it's merged with another question, so you might need to unlock it in order to edit the tag out. I agree that it would be nice to be able to blacklist them more easily.